# my player can look up and down but when my player look right and left its shaking. i'm following tutorial on brackeys

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

Can you guys help me? I want my player to look normal and not keep shaking. My game is first-person. When my player looks up and down, it looks normal but when the player looks right or left, it's shaking. I'm following tutorial by Brackeys and the game is normal different from mine.

```
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float mouseSentivity = 100f;

    public Transform playerBody;

    float xRotation = 0f;

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSentivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSentivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason it's shaky is you're resetting the rotation every frame with `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);`. Replace this with another `.Rotate` for the `xRotation` instead. Also Google for 'Unity player controller' or 'Unity camera controller' - there are hundreds of examples of how to do it well.

Comment: I just realized I had a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX, Space.World);
```

Comment: I just realized I had a typo